# How to Embed an .m3u8 link

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming

The title itself describes my problem. I am having trouble in embedding `.m3u8` links.

I had also reffered to similar questions on stackoverflow but still wasn't able to embed the video file.

Some People suggested me to use Hls player but it still didn't work.
I am sharing that code please go through it.

```js
<script>
      if(Hls.isSupported()) {
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource('https://d26g5bnklkwsh4.cloudfront.net/adf856d9-a233-484b-a730-f7ac57c53aa5/master.m3u8');
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED,function() {
          video.play();
      });
     }
     // hls.js is not supported on platforms that do not have Media Source Extensions (MSE) enabled.
     // When the browser has built-in HLS support (check using `canPlayType`), we can provide an HLS manifest (i.e. .m3u8 URL) directly to the video element throught the `src` property.
     // This is using the built-in support of the plain video element, without using hls.js.
      else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
        video.src = 'https://d26g5bnklkwsh4.cloudfront.net/adf856d9-a233-484b-a730-f7ac57c53aa5/master.m3u8';
        video.addEventListener('canplay',function() {
          video.play();
        });
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>01</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
   <video id="video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}">

   </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your file is "embedded" when you add it to the source code of the page. Maybe you mean it's **not playable**? If yes to not playing, then I suspect it is because your **file is encrypted**. Try checking... **(1)** Test with any other M3U8 that is not encrypted. **(2)** If it works with other M3U8 but not yours, then you need a key for decryption. Check how to use a decryption key in HLS.JS then provide one to the player.

Comment: For your M3U8 there is a key inside each file called `main.m3u8` (depends on which resolution you pick). To find `main.m3u8`, save your shown link as file, then open in a text editor (_eg:_ Notepad on Windows) and get link for a specific resolution, then load that M3U8 by replacing the `master.m3u8` text part with text of URL for the link... example (rest of link)+`/master.m3u8` becomes (rest of link) +`/hls/360/main.m3u8/` then find the key inside `main.m3u8`. Look for `#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128` as line with the key.

Comment: Can you please give me a .m3u8 link which is not encrypted so that I can make sure what is the problem going on

Comment: You can try: https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8 ... Test that unencrypted [M3U8 link](https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8) with your HLS.js player. If it works, then your (encrypted) stream really does need to use the key from inside the other M3U8 files. It's not my area of expertise but can advise if you try something (_eg:_ [show](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76160086/edit) some Javascript code).